# How to open angular web page when deploying a Spring Boot application on Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, angular, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot + Angular 2 application which I want to package as war and deploy on Tomcat.

I am able to integrated everything successfully but when I try to hit localhost url, I get a 404.

When I build Angular and Spring Boot independently and run application as Spring Boot main class, I am able to see `index.html` content. Not sure what to configure further.

Here is application folder structure:
[image]

Here goes the `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.roger.mylab</groupId>
<artifactId>MyPortal</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.1</version>

<name>MyPortal Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud-aws-version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-aws-version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <angular.project.location>src/frontend</angular.project.location>
        <angular.project.nodeinstallation>node_installation</angular.project.nodeinstallation>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-aws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-aws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP settings -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>myportal</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- It will install nodejs and npm -->
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v9.2.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory 
                    to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Plugin to copy the content of /angular/dist/ directory to output 
        directory (ie/ /target/) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/${angular.project.location}/dist</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And finally, the content of `.angular-cli.json`:

```
   {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Adding `proxy.conf.json`:

```
{
"/myportalapi" :{
"target" : "http://localhost:8080",
"secure" : false
}
```

}

The context path of the application mentioned in `application.properties` is `/myportal`

I want to map `http://localhost:8080/myportal/` to open `index.html`. Currently throws 404.

Comment: Can you provide the proxy.conf.json?

Comment: Did you invoke Maven before running the application? I'm not seeing the `node_modules` folder, nor the `dist` folder and neither do I see the `src/main/resources/static` folder in your screenshot, so I'm not sure if the Maven frontend plugin has been executed.

Comment: @g00glen00b: Maven is executed successfully and there is a static folder inside resources.

Comment: Have updated with `proxy.conf.json` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` file modify `build` script as:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myportal/
```